# PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

please bear with me as I'm just learning PDO. Anyway I keep getting the error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object**

The code is below, am I doing anything wrong? The function itself is being called out on another file as so:

```
$result = $database->confirmIPAddress($this->ip);
```

Function code:

```
function confirmIPAddress($value) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT attempts, (CASE when lastlogin is not NULL and DATE_ADD(LastLogin, INTERVAL `.TIME_PERIOD.` MINUTE)>NOW() then 1 else 0 end) as Denied `.
    ` FROM `.TBL_ATTEMPTS.` WHERE ip = :ip");
    $stmt->execute(array(':ip' => $value));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Verify that at least one login attempt is in database
   if (!$data) {
     return 0;
   } 
   if ($data["attempts"] >= ATTEMPTS_NUMBER)
   {
      if($data["Denied"] == 1)
      {
         return 1;
      }
     else
     {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($value);
        return 0;
     }
   }
   return 0;  
  }
```

Comment: maybe `$db` is not known within that function?

Comment: You haven't set `$db` to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepare() returns **false** if there's any parse error, or else throws an exception if you have configured PDO to use that error mode.

Your statement has some syntax problems.  You appear to be embedding a PHP constant for your table name and the time period, but you have used back-ticks to delimit your string.  You need to use double-quotes in this case.

Current statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT attempts, (CASE when lastlogin is not NULL and
    DATE_ADD(LastLogin, INTERVAL `.TIME_PERIOD.` MINUTE)>NOW() then 1 else 0 end) 
    as Denied `.
  ` FROM `.TBL_ATTEMPTS.` WHERE ip = :ip");
```

Should be:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT attempts, (CASE when lastlogin is not NULL and
    DATE_ADD(LastLogin, INTERVAL ".TIME_PERIOD." MINUTE)>NOW() then 1 else 0 end) 
    as Denied
  FROM `".TBL_ATTEMPTS."` WHERE ip = :ip");
```

Comment: Thank you good sir. You're solution worked, just curious is it right to do `".TBL_ATTEMPTS."`? Or is ".TBL_ATTEMPTS." acceptable too?

Comment: You would use the back-ticks if TBL_ATTEMPTS needs to be delimited -- that is, if the name of your table contains special characters, whitespace, or an SQL reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variable scoping issue, nothing to do specifically with PDO. In your function, you use the variable `$db`. I assume this is a global variable you set in the main code of your script. before calling the function. In PHP, global variables are not automatically visible inside functions. You must either pass the variable in as a parameter, or use a `global` declaration:

```
function confirmIPAddress($value) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fixed it :), thank you. I keep getting  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 now, any fix on that?

Comment: See my answer for the fix for the syntax error.

Comment: any other solution to this problem because i get same problem even if i have a global variable